# ASP.NET Web Forms Form Authentication with Custom Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, membership-provider

I have a new ASP.NET Web Forms website and am trying to setup Authentication. I am using a custom DLL that opens up a connection like so:

`Session s = new Session();
s.Start("ürl", "username", "password");`

After that, I have an active Session if everything worked out alright with Authentication. If not, I get an error message. This is all I have access to, and I need to build typical authentication around this and I want to do it the "right" way. I am not sure if or how to use a `MembershipProvider`.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to create a custom membership provider.  Depending on which version of ASP.NET you're using, it's likely just a matter of building a class which implements an abstract provider and then specifying that class as your provider in the `Web.config`.  As long as this service provides the functionality needed by the membership provider interface then the backing service is essentially transparent to ASP.NET.

Comment: @David I have implemented the MembershipProvider, but I am not sure how that should hook up to my authenticated User or anything like that. I have just filled out `ValidateUser` in the `MembershipProvider`

Comment: Basically, how does my MembershipProvider interact with my User? Right now the `ValidateUser` method is being called and works, but then some User is shoved into the system (not sure how) and the system is using that User, but I never set a User anywhere.

Comment: The provider usage is built into a lot of the ASP.NET objects.  So if you're using a custom provider defined in your `Web.config` then for example when you get information from the `User` object (in `Page` or `Controller` depending on which you're using) it would use that provider to get that information.